# "Licensed" vs. "registered"

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, legalese

I found these terms while doing some research about insurance:

> Agents must usually be **licensed** in the province or territory in which
>   they do business.
>   Brokers must usually be **registered** in the province or territory in which
>   they do business.

What is the difference between *licensed* and *registered*?

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  Could you provide a little context to your question?  While similar, there are many situations which these terms might diverge in meaning.  For instance, in the US, *guns* are registered, *people* are licensed (to carry them).

Comment: Hey @erich i had added a description

Comment: that's exactly what this question needed.  your edit provides valuable context that will aid others to answer the question.  thanks!

Comment: Can you add sources or authorities (or even context) for your two examples- i.e. Agents requiring License and Brokers requiring registration? The insurance industry is fraught with these terms and they apply differently in different jurisdictions and even for different functions within the same jurisdiction. For example, Brokers must usually be licensed to conduct brokerage business, not merely 'registered'.

Comment: At the first approximation they mean the same thing.  Which term is used where is more a question of how the laws are written than it is of English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb ***to license*** (noun ***licence***) means *to authorise*, or *to grant permission*.

So, after passing a test of competence to drive, one is ***licensed*** to drive a motor vehicle and given a printed ***driving licence***.

***To register*** means to enter something on an official list. All motor vehicles in the UK have to be ***registered*** with the Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency (DVLA).

The two words are linked and are sometimes used interchangeably, simply because in order for something to be registered, it often has to be licensed, and vice-versa. And registration can be evidence that something is licensed.

Answer (score 0):

A registered entity is someone which is in a list of any registering agency - be it a registrar of companies, stock-exchange etc. The entity may be registered whether or not it is functional or not or doing good or bad.

A licence is typically granted to an entity to 'do something' - so a licensed entity is the one which which has permission or is authorized for specific work or function.

Applicability of whether a company must registered 'under something' to be licensed 'to do something' and vice versa depends on the law of the land.

Comment: "Registered" may also be used to describe something or someone's presence in a database.